# Magento customer group ID

Tags: magento, paypal

I have made some changes to Magento order email templates and code so that customers in retail and wholesale customer groups receive differently formatted email confirmations. i.e. One group receives an email showing VAT/TAX the other does not.

This works fine except for orders paid with Paypal. With a paypal order my logic for detecting the group ID is failing. Can anyone shed any light as to why this might be happening? Is the response coming back from paypal somehow not associated with the customers group? If so can I perform a check after a successful paypal ipn response to ensure the system keeps the customer in the right group.

I am retrieving the customer group from the customer/session perhaps I should be getting it directly from the database?

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: why not get the customer from order object and group from there?

Comment: Thanks, that is the way to do it I think with $_order->getCustomerGroupId().

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Anton for pointing me in the right direction. After a paypal payment group ID in the session is set to 0 - not logged in!

Makes much more sense when working on events and code after an order is placed to get customer info from the saved order, so in my case the following returned the correct Group ID for me to use in order confirmation email code etc.

```
$_order = $this->getOrder();
// get group id from order
$groupId = $_order->getCustomerGroupId();
```